# Unable to Boot to Either System After Dual Boot Install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, hp

I just performed a clean dual boot install on an HP laptop that came with Windows 8.  The install said it had completed successfully, but when I restart the machine, or power down and power back up, it boots straight into Windows 8 rather than giving me the boot options.  I feel like I missed something obvious here.  I did check the side by side install, the drive was partitioned during install, and, as I said, the install finished properly.  I've probably done a dozen of these dual boot installs and I've never run into this issue before.  Any insight would be appreciated.

*** UPDATE ***

Something went tragically wrong with EASYBCD and I am now no longer able to boot into either Windows or Linux.  Windows no longer appears as an option at boot, and Linux still comes up as OS Not Usuable.  In short, the only thing I can boot to is the Linux Live USB that I used for the install.  I tried boot-repair, and while it said it was successful it changed absolutely nothing.  The URL for the boot-repair report is

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11047074

One further edit which may clarify some things.  Running boot-repair from the live usb only loads the linux partition.  In short, it doesn't even see the Windows partition and, as a result, no MBR options are available.  It is only trying to fix grub, when the issue at least right now is getting Windows to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Get **Boot-Repair Tool** and burn it into Live USB. Follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).  You can also try **[EasyBCD](http://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-the-boot-menu-windows-8/)**. post back if this did not solve your problem with the exact error you are getting.

Comment: I'm working the EasyBCD right now but I feel like maybe this was the wrong way to go.  I have their version of boot loader up with Linux as an option, but when I try to boot into Linux I get an OS Failed To Load error.  I went in and wiped the previous Linux install and re-installed, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to boot into Windows by fixing it using a Windows Vista/7/8 Disk. To do this, boot from Installation Disk, **Select Repair** and enter a **command prompt**. Type in:-

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

Restart your PC and see if you can now boot into Windows.

Comment: Both operations completed successfully.  They had no effect.  Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: Have you formatted your windows partition? Also, are you getting the grub bootloader screen first?

Comment: Why would I format the Windows partition?  I'm trying to rescue the data on it at this point.  And yes, I am getting the grub bootloader.  And with some further, more intensive work with boot-repair I am now at least getting the Windows options from the grub bootloader.  However, selecting those options leads to an error because the boot file on the Windows partition is missing.